# Display Data from database table of module to Prestashop Product Page - Prestashop 1.7.7.6

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I find in internet a CRUD module (create, read, update, delete) and it works very well in backoffice of Prestashop 1.7.7.6

And now I want to select data from module table and display in front office prestashop product page tpl file

How can i do ?

please help me

Thanks You very much in advance

structure of crud module moduletest :

```
- Classes / Moduletesttabletest.php
- Controllers / Admin / Adminmoduletest.php
- moduletest.php
```

Display Data from database table of module to Prestashop Product Page  - Prestashop 1.7.7.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select hook there data will be displayed

Than add this hook to your moduletest.php file in two places.
For example to show data on product page near price block you can use hook ProductPriceBlock

1. There is public function install() in yor module. It will register hook, so prestashop knows that it`s function need to be called

   ```
     public function install()
    {    ....
        $this->registerHook('header') &&
        $this->registerHook('backOfficeHeader') &&
      ++$this->registerHook('displayProductPriceBlock');
    }
   ```
2. At the end of file before closing code block "}" add code to retrive and display data to according function:

> ```
>  public function hookdisplayProductPriceBlock($params)
>  {    //     your code goes here         }
> ```

3. Reset module in modules Modules manager - this will actualy register hook after you make changes to source code
4. To use template you need according tpl file in /views/templates/front/ subdirectory of module and call it by

   ```
    $this->display(__FILE__, 'my-template.tpl');
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , i put this code :  public function hookdisplayProductPriceBlock($params){
  $result = Db::getInstance()->getValue('SELECT `champ_varchar_test` FROM `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'module_test` WHERE `id_module_test` = 1');
  if (strlen($result) > 0) {
                return array(
                    'additionalDescription' => $result
                );
            }   
  }                                                                                                                                         how can display in TPL file prestashop ? please help , thanks

Comment: you can just echo it (not good but fast).<br>to use template you need according tpl file in /views/templates/front/ subdirectory of module and call it by<br>$this->display(__FILE__, 'my-template.tpl');

Comment: look at step 4 - there is proper format

Comment: i put this code in moduletest.php : public function hookdisplayProductPriceBlock($params) {   

  
  $result = "just a test";  
  $this->smarty->assign (array('variable' => $result)); 

   $this->display(__FILE__, 'moduletest.tpl');

 } and in modules/moduletest/views/templates/front/moduletest.tpl, i put this : <br/>
{$variable}  but nothing show in product page detail , how can i resolve it ???, many thanks

Comment: not shure where is problem. check apache error log and prestashop prouction log

Comment: anything to put in product.tpl ?

Comment: product.tpl must be in smarty format. If you don`t have appropriate html there, your variable will be somwhere in html code, but not properly rendered on page

Comment: many thanks @panariga, I solve a problem : i use this hook displayAfterDescription and i create this function in main file module : moduletest.php : public function hookDisplayAfterDescription(){ return 'just a test'; }  and i add in \themes\classic\templates\catalog\product.tpl this line : {hook h='displayAfterDescription'} , I reinstall the module after modification and Its working !!!!!! thanks You

Comment: don`t forget to backup changes in product.tpl as it will be owerriten on prestashop upgrade. Also you don`t need to reinstall module to register hooks - you can just reset it